# Android custom notification sound not working on Chinese phones like Redmi and Vivo

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

In my app I have created a channel to show **custom notifications with a custom sound**. It works fine on most phones. But there are 2 unexpected behaviors I faced on 2 different types of phones.

**On some Redmi phones I face this behavior**:

The notification channel gets created but the sound is automatically turned off for that channel. I have to manually go and turn on the sound for that channel. I do not want that to be done manually.

**On Vivo Phones I face these behaviors:**

1) The notification channel gets created but plays the default notification sound instead of the custom sound I have set

2) Sometimes it doesn't play any sound

3) Static notifications that are supposed to remain fixed can be swiped the notification bar easily.

Is there anyway I can fix these issues programmatically?

This is my code for reference:

```
val attributes: AudioAttributes? = AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
    .build()
val sound: Uri? = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.notif)

val vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)

val noisyChannel = NotificationChannel("NOISY_ID", "Noisy Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
noisyChannel.enableLights(true)
noisyChannel.enableVibration(true)
noisyChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
noisyChannel.setShowBadge(true)
noisyChannel.setSound(sound, attributes)
noisyChannel.setBypassDnd(true)
noisyChannel.enableVibration(true)
noisyChannel.lockscreenVisibility = VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
noisyChannel.setShowBadge(true)
noisyChannel.vibrationPattern = vibrationPattern
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(noisyChannel)
```